# Why does python's Exception's repr keep track of passed object's to __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Please see the below code snippet:

```py
In [1]: class A(Exception):
   ...:     def __init__(self, b):
   ...:         self.message = b.message
   ...: 

In [2]: class B:
   ...:     message = "hello"
   ...: 

In [3]: A(B())
Out[3]: __main__.A(<__main__.B at 0x14af96790>)

In [4]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self, b):
   ...:         self.message = b.message
   ...: 

In [5]: A(B())
Out[5]: <__main__.A at 0x10445b0a0>
```

if `A` subclasses from `Exception`, its `repr` returns a reference to `B()` even though we only pass `B()`'s message attribute.

Why is this the intentional behavior in `Exception.repr` and how does it work in python psuedocode if possible given the cpython code isn't too readable ?

Comment: I'll do you one better. Here's a standalone Python script that exhibits the same behavior: [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##RYw7CoAwEET7PcVitYLY2AkWETxH8LNqQGPIptDTR0XFVw0zj3FHmDdbxAj90oqgombv2QWz2bQEvBh4RK2NNUFrEl7GDLt3urmbfGWRdmKssPsyvIf1o/5GohIA540N5Nl5UlRTegExng). It's very interesting behavior.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo this also seems like an artifact of the REPL you shared ...

Comment: That same script runs and produces identical output on my own machine. I can reproduce the behavior reliably on several machines. It's likely this is intended behavior. As for *how* it's happening, that's a much more interesting question, and I'm curious to find out.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? This is just how [CPython implementation of `__repr__` for `Exception`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/exceptions.c#L121) is implemented. As to why, this is anyone's guess, but possibly because having the error message in the representation is generally helpful.

Comment: @VincentSavard I believe the question is *how* it retains a reference to `b` in order for that reference to be printed by `repr`, when `__init__` only stores `b.message` and not `b` itself.

Comment: @kaya3 yes exactly

Comment: @kaya3 As per the source code I shared above, the CPython implementation keeps the tuple of arguments received in `__init__`. My point is mostly that the _why_ is possibly subjective, unlike the _how_, which is why I would have liked a clarification on what kind of answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo - you are right has nothing to do with ipython, I ran the code with python 2.7 by mistake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a Python object is created, it is the class's `__new__` method that is called, and `__init__` is then called on the new instance that the `__new__` method returns (assuming it returned a new instance, which sometimes it doesn't).

Your overridden `__init__` method doesn't keep a reference to `b`, but you didn't override `__new__`, so you inherit the `__new__` method defined here ([CPython source link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/058fb35b57ca8c5063d16ec818e668b3babfea65/Objects/exceptions.c#L35)):

```c
static PyObject *
BaseException_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    // ...
    if (args) {
        self->args = args;
        Py_INCREF(args);
        return (PyObject *)self;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I omitted the parts that are not relevant. As you can see, the `__new__` method of the `BaseException` class stores a reference to the tuple of arguments used when creating the exception, and this tuple is therefore available for the `__repr__` method to print a reference to the objects used to instantiate the exception. So it's this tuple which retains a reference to the original argument `b`. This is consistent with the general expectation that `repr` should return Python code which would create an object in the same state, if it can.

Note that it is only `args`, not `kwds`, which has this behaviour; the `__new__` method doesn't store a reference to `kwds` and `__repr__` doesn't print it, so we should expect not to see the same behaviour if the constructor is called with a keyword argument instead of a positional argument. Indeed, that is what we observe:

```py
>>> A(B())
A(<__main__.B object at 0x7fa8e7a23860>,)
>>> A(b=B())
A()
```

A bit strange since the two `A` objects are supposed to have the same state, but that's how the code is written, anyway.

Comment: It's actually quite interesting that `BaseException.__new__` *doesn't* store a reference to kwargs. I wonder if that's an oversight. I've certainly used keyword arguments in custom exception types before, so it seems odd to omit them.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I think I've found the trick. [Here's](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/058fb35b57ca8c5063d16ec818e668b3babfea65/Objects/exceptions.c#L38) the C source code, but I'll reimplement something similar in Python to demonstrate.

In addition to the usual `__init__` (which you're overriding), Python also has a magic method called [`__new__`](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#construction). When you construct an `A` as `A(B())`, it's doing something roughly like

```
b = B()
a = A.__new__(A, b)
a.__init__(b)
```

Now, you've overridden `A.__init__`, so `Exception.__init__` never gets called. But `A.__new__` is simply `Exception.__new__` (more precisely, it's `BaseException.__new__`, which is essentially the C source code I linked). And, based on the linked code, that's roughly

```
class BaseException:
  def __new__(cls, *args):
    obj = object.__new__(cls)
    obj.args = args
    return obj
```

So we explicitly store the arguments tuple in a field called `args` on the exception object. This is the *actual* arguments tuple passed to the constructor, even if we override `__init__`. So `repr` is just referencing `self.args` to get the original arguments back.

Note that I'm being a bit imprecise here. If you check `BaseException.__new__` in the REPL, you'll see that it's still `object.__new__`. The C callbacks work differently and use some compiler magic we don't have access to, but the basic idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

We can explore the difference with Ipython's tab complete.

```
In [230]: a=A(B())
In [231]: a
Out[231]: __main__.A(<__main__.B at 0x7f29cd1e71c0>)
```

With ipython tab complete:

```
In [234]: a.
             args             a.bin           
             message          a.npy           
             with_traceback() a.t1  
In [234]: a.args
Out[234]: (<__main__.B at 0x7f29cd1e71c0>,)
```

The class without Exception, only has one attribute, `message`:

```
In [235]: a1=A1(B())
In [236]: a1
Out[236]: <__main__.A1 at 0x7f29ccc21a60>
In [237]: a1.message
Out[237]: 'hello'
```

and a plain Exception:

```
In [238]: e=Exception(B())
In [239]: e
Out[239]: Exception(<__main__.B at 0x7f29ccd0e790>)
In [240]: e.
             args            
             with_traceback()
```

And using `a` as an exception:

```
In [240]: raise(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-240-cf5e5bb7d43e>", line 1, in <module>
    raise(a)
A: <__main__.B object at 0x7f29cd1e71c0>
```